Why does my rigged arm look like a twisted plastic bottle?
Blender novice here. I've been trying to figure out how to cleanly rig this really basic arm (see below), but regardless of automatic or empty groups, it ends up with this horrible twist. This has happened to me before, but I can't find any clear solutions online other than for twisting in Rigify (I'm just making this from the basic armature). My topology has lots of loop cuts, but even smoothing out the weight painting just makes another part of the chest area deform really badly.
I feel like this is a really simple problem with a very obvious solution, but I'm having trouble with it and would really appreciate some guidance. What does one do to smooth out a twist??? I still want the arm to be able to move within normal rotation, from the elbow pointing fully down to fully up (180), but no matter which orientation I set as "normal", the other directions end up twisting like this.



Have you checked the normals? It should be blue. For the red faces, you have to flip the normals in Edit mode.

Problem: I think the issue is coming from the IK setup of forearm. Try to tweak the rotation value of the Pole Angle under IK constraint.


Tip for better IK setup: make sure you have small bending between upper arm and forearm. and move back the pole bone on the direction of bending. this way the pole bone's movement will give you more predictable result.

